# "The specified formula cann't be entered b/c it uses more than 64 levels of nesting"

Tags: excel, excel-formula

> "The specified formula cann't be entered b/c it uses more than 64 levels of nesting"

How i can solve this using `IF` Function?

```
=IF('Research design'!L7=1,'Research design'!B7,IF('Research design'!L8=1,'Research design'!B8, IF('Research design'!L9=1,'Research design'!B9,IF('Research design'!L10=1,'Research design'!B10, IF('Research design'!L11=1,'Research design'!B11,IF('Research design'!L12=1,'Research design'!B12, IF('Research design'!L13=1,'Research design'!B13,IF('Research design'!L14=1,'Research design'!B14, IF('Research design'!L15=1,'Research design'!B15,IF('Research design'!L16=1,'Research design'!B16, IF('Research design'!L17=1,'Research design'!B17,IF('Research design'!L18=1,'Research design'!B18, IF('Research design'!L19=1,'Research design'!B19,IF('Research design'!L20=1,'Research design'!B20, IF('Research design'!L21=1,'Research design'!B21,IF('Research design'!L22=1,'Research design'!B22, IF('Research design'!L23=1,'Research design'!B23,IF('Research design'!L24=1,'Research design'!B24, IF('Research design'!L25=1,'Research design'!B25,IF('Research design'!L26=1,'Research design'!B26, IF('Research design'!L27=1,'Research design'!B27,IF('Research design'!L28=1,'Research design'!B28, IF('Research design'!L29=1,'Research design'!B29,IF('Research design'!L30=1,'Research design'!B30, IF('Research design'!L31=1,'Research design'!B31,IF('Research design'!L32=1,'Research design'!B32, IF('Research design'!L33=1,'Research design'!B33,IF('Research design'!L34=1,'Research design'!B34, IF('Research design'!L35=1,'Research design'!B35,IF('Research design'!L36=1,'Research design'!B36, IF('Research design'!L37=1,'Research design'!B37,IF('Research design'!L38=1,'Research design'!B38, IF('Research design'!L39=1,'Research design'!B39,IF('Research design'!L40=1,'Research design'!B40, IF('Research design'!L41=1,'Research design'!B41,IF('Research design'!L42=1,'Research design'!B42, IF('Research design'!L43=1,'Research design'!B43,IF('Research design'!L44=1,'Research design'!B44, IF('Research design'!L45=1,'Research design'!B45,IF('Research design'!L46=1,'Research design'!B46, IF('Research design'!L47=1,'Research design'!B47,IF('Research design'!L48=1,'Research design'!B48, IF('Research design'!L49=1,'Research design'!B49,IF('Research design'!L50=1,'Research design'!B50, IF('Research design'!L51=1,'Research design'!B51,IF('Research design'!L52=1,'Research design'!B52, IF('Research design'!L53=1,'Research design'!B53,IF('Research design'!L54=1,'Research design'!B54, IF('Research design'!L55=1,'Research design'!B55,IF('Research design'!L56=1,'Research design'!B56, IF('Research design'!L57=1,'Research design'!B57,IF('Research design'!L58=1,'Research design'!B58, IF('Research design'!L59=1,'Research design'!B59,IF('Research design'!L60=1,'Research design'!B60, IF('Research design'!L61=1,'Research design'!B61,IF('Research design'!L62=1,'Research design'!B62, IF('Research design'!L63=1,'Research design'!B63,IF('Research design'!L64=1,'Research design'!B64, IF('Research design'!L65=1,'Research design'!B65,IF('Research design'!L66=1,'Research design'!B66, IF('Research design'!L67=1,'Research design'!B67,IF('Research design'!L68=1,'Research design'!B68, IF('Research design'!L69=1,'Research design'!B69,IF('Research design'!L70=1,'Research design'!B70, IF('Research design'!L71=1,'Research design'!B71,IF('Research design'!L72=1,'Research design'!B72, IF('Research design'!L73=1,'Research design'!B73,IF('Research design'!L74=1,'Research design'!B74, IF('Research design'!L75=1,'Research design'!B75,IF('Research design'!L76=1,'Research design'!B76, IF('Research design'!L77=1,'Research design'!B77,IF('Research design'!L78=1,'Research design'!B78, IF('Research design'!L79=1,'Research design'!B79,IF('Research design'!L80=1,'Research design'!B80, IF('Research design'!L81=1,'Research design'!B81,IF('Research design'!L82=1,'Research design'!B82, IF('Research design'!L83=1,'Research design'!B83,IF('Research design'!L84=1,'Research design'!B84, IF('Research design'!L85=1,'Research design'!B85,IF('Research design'!L86=1,'Research design'!B86, IF('Research design'!L87=1,'Research design'!B87,IF('Research design'!L88=1,'Research design'!B88, IF('Research design'!L89=1,'Research design'!B89,IF('Research design'!L90=1,'Research design'!B90, IF('Research design'!L91=1,'Research design'!B91,IF('Research design'!L92=1,'Research design'!B92, IF('Research design'!L93=1,'Research design'!B93,IF('Research design'!L94=1,'Research design'!B94, IF('Research design'!L95=1,'Research design'!B95,IF('Research design'!L96=1,'Research design'!B96, IF('Research design'!L97=1,'Research design'!B97,IF('Research design'!L98=1,'Research design'!B98, IF('Research design'!L99=1,'Research design'!B99,IF('Research design'!L100=1,'Research design'!B100, IF('Research design'!L101=1,'Research design'!B101,IF('Research design'!L102=1,'Research design'!B102,IF('Research design'!L103=1,'Research design'!B103, IF('Research design'!L104=1,'Research design'!B104,IF('Research design'!L105=1,'Research design'!B105,IF('Research design'!L106=1,'Research design'!B106,IF('Research design'!L107=1,'Research design'!B107,IF('Research design'!L108=1,'Research design'!B108,IF('Research design'!L109=1,'Research design'!B109,IF('Research design'!L110=1,'Research design'!B110,IF('Research design'!L111=1,'Research design'!B111,IF('Research design'!L112=1,'Research design'!B112,IF('Research design'!L113=1,'Research design'!B113,IF('Research design'!L114=1,'Research design'!B114,IF('Research design'!L115=1,'Research design'!B115, IF('Research design'!L116=1,'Research design'!B116,IF('Research design'!L117=1,'Research design'!B117,IF('Research design'!L118=1,'Research design'!B118,IF('Research design'!L119=1,'Research design'!B119, IF('Research design'!L120=1,'Research design'!B120,IF('Research design'!L121=1,'Research design'!B121, IF('Research design'!L122=1,'Research design'!B122,IF('Research design'!L123=1,'Research design'!B123,IF('Research design'!L124=1,'Research design'!B124,IF('Research design'!L125=1,'Research design'!B125,IF('Research design'!L126=1,'Research design'!B126," "))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly what you are trying to do then first thing that comes to mind is `INDEX` and `MATCH` to get the first `1` value in your `L` range to return `B` column value. Something like:

```
=INDEX(B7:B126,MATCH(1,L7:L126,0))
```

In case no `1` can be found `MATCH` returns an error you could handle through `IFERROR` for example.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Microsoft365 you can use XLOOKUP()

```
=XLOOKUP(1,L7:L123,B7:B123)
```

If you do not use Microsoft365 you can use

```
=VLOOKUP(1,CHOOSE({2\1},B7:B123,L7:L123),2,0)
```

Answer (score 0):

> How i can solve this using IF Function?

With that many ifs & arguments, you can't. Even if you re-work it & use if(AND or if(OR it will still have issues.

So if you need to individually keep tab on the cells you reference;

```
=CHOOSE(MATCH(1,L7:L126,0),B7,B8,B9,B10,B11,B12)
```

Match returns the row number & will return the first one, much like in your if statement. CHOOSE will call the match item returned, similar to Index.

Note that the CHOOSE function has a limitation https://support.office.com/en-us/article/CHOOSE-function-FC5C184F-CB62-4EC7-A46E-38653B98F5BC & can only support 254 arguments.

The Index/Match is probably a better solution.